# Creating ASP.NET content in a new page, (pop up window)

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, popup

I have an ASP.NET button which displays a report (a datatable and binded to my gridview) on my `default.aspx` page.

However I want it to show it in a new page, and when button is clicked again, it should open a third page.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript's `window.open` property for this purpose.

You will have to use window.open on `clientclick` of button so that it will open window as a pop up.

It will be as below:

```
window.open('default.aspx','name','width=200,height=200');
```

**EDIT:**

Can also try as follows:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>child=window.open('default.aspx');</script>");
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>child=window.open('default1.aspx');</script>");
    }
```

Comment: this only opens 1 pop up page, it is not working for more than 1 page.

Comment: isn't that open 2 pages at the same time? I need my application to open a page, and when clicked, open another page.

Comment: yes it will open window at a same time. You will need to find correct event at wich you want to open second window

Answer (score 1):

write two pages from one page open another page in popup using the link below..
after you have passed the id to the popup get it like this
    request.Querystring["Id"].tostring();

```
<a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open('yourNewPag.aspx?id='+'<%id to be passed to the popup,e.g. #Eval<"Id"> %>','Popup','toolbar=no, location=yes,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=700,height=350,left=430,top=23'); return false;">OpenPOPUP</a>
```

Comment: if this has has not solve the problem then comment here if it has solve the problem then please mark it as answer so that other can find answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, (`Window.Open`) to get it open in a new page. Check this example:

http://windowopen.codeplex.com/

Comment: and how can I change the content?, as in my example I have to use my datatable in that newly opened page. And will this example work for more than 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use light-weight [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/) Jquery !

```
   <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href='popUp.aspx'>
                    ClickToOpen</a>
```

Comment: you can add this link in `popUp.aspx` too , and you can open third page from `popUp.aspx` !